# gcc double printf precision - wrong output

Tags: linux, gcc, floating-point, printf, floating-point-precision

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h> 
int main()
{
    double f = 1717.1800000000001;
    wprintf(L"double      %.20G\n", f);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs (and expected below):

```
double      1717.1800000000000637
double      1717.1800000000001
```

This is on Ubuntu 11.10 x64 (but also when compiling for 32 bit).

The problem that I try to solve, is that on Windows it outputs the number exactly like in code, and I need to make low-level formatting (swprintf) to work like in Windows, for portability issues.

Comment: 1717.1800000000001 is not exactly representable as double, so you only get a value near to it in `f`. The value stored in f is exactly 1717.180000000000063664629124104976654052734375. The problem is now that windows does only output 17 significant digits, although 20 were requested (which is a known bug, AFAIK it's somewhere in their bug databse). If you can't limit the field length to a sane value (like 17), you need a wrapper to mimic this bug.

Comment: This is very interesting to know, can you remember the exact bug? This is what I need, to make linux version to work like Windows even with its bugs.

Comment: Actually I set .17 instead of .20 and now linux/windows are completely compatible. If you change your comment to answer I'd gladly accept it. But if you can find the exact bug link it would be even more helpful.

Comment: I don't remember the bug number, but I remember it has been closed as WONTFIX. So you can probably rely on it.

Comment: That being said, you're on a fool's errand if you expect results of FP computations to be bit-for-bit equal with different compilers and on different OS'es. Beyond the obvious issues like compiler optimizations changing the ordering of FP operations and bugs in MS libc, you have differences such as glibc printf using roundTiesToEven and MSVC AFAIK using roundTiesToAway.

Comment: Well, for IEEE double you can actually expect the same behavior across different compilers and platforms, they are standardized. For the rounding in the libc printf I am not so sure. Is there a standard for printing IEEE conforming doubles?

Comment: @drhirsch: With more aggressize optimization flags, compilers often optimize things such that bit-for-bit equal results no longer result. (e.g. "a+b-a" => b). And for 32-bit x86, there's of course extra fun due to the x87 excess precision issue, giving you different results depending on the register allocator. Also, MSVC IIRC sets the x87 precision to 53 bits, whereas GCC leaves it at 64 bits. And then of course, few if any libm's in usage today guarantee correctly rounded results, again giving a source of errors in the last bits.

Comment: @drhirsch: Wrt printf, IEEE 754 requires that binary<->decimal conversions are correctly rounded per the current rounding mode. As the default rounding mode is roundTiesToEven, one can argue that the glibc behavior is the correct one.

Comment: I got _exact_ match between windows and linux when I set precision to 17, so (for now) I don't care about possible differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1717.1800000000001 is not exactly representable as double, so you only get a value near to it in f. The value stored in f is exactly 1717.180000000000063664629124104976654052734375.

The problem is now that windows does only output 17 significant digits, although 20 were requested (which is a known bug, AFAIK it's somewhere in their bug database).

If you can't limit the field length to a sane value (like  `"%.17G"`), you need a wrapper to mimic this bug.

Comment: The bug seems to be this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/329278/printf-sprintf-do-not-print-enough-significant-digits-for-exact-binary-fractions

Comment: @queen3: Yes, that's the bug report (I wrote it). See my article http://www.exploringbinary.com/print-precision-of-dyadic-fractions-varies-by-language/ for the gory details.

Comment: @queen3: Well spotted. Interesting to see the story behind that bug.

Answer (score 0):

`wprintf` function is implemented by standard C library, not by gcc.

Number `1717.1800000000001` has 13 digits after the floating point. However, it doesn't have exact representation in 64-bit binary floating point format.

Format `"%.20G"` requires outputting 20 significant digits which is the count of digits in `1717.1800000000000637`. Hence this output is what expected. Either Windows standard C library treats the format differently or makes incorrect rounding.

On the other hand, you can require a specific number of digits after the floating point by using `"%f"` format, e.g. `"%.13f"` rounds the output to exactly 13 digits after the floating point an it prints `1717.1800000000001` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your expected output conflicts with your format string. "%.20G" means you want 20 significant digits, and that's what you're getting. If you want 17 significant digits, as your expected output has, use "%.17G".

Answer (score -1):

```
double f = 1717.1800000000001;
```

This line of code cannot be executed accurately. The constant has 17 decimal digits of precision, a double has 15.9.

Comment: The value given by the OP can't be exactly represented, that much is true. But the rest of your answer is wrong, which can be shown quite easily: The line `f=1717.180000000000063664629124104976654052734375` would be executed accuratly, although it has even more digits.

Comment: But that's not what's in the line of code that can't be executed accurately, is it? And you are going to have to show me the binary representation of 1717.180000000000063664629124104976654052734375 because a double still only has 53 bits, and that value needs more.

Comment: No, it does need _exactly_ 53 bits. Just try it. Execute with an calcluator which is able to handle arbitrary length arithmetic (like gp) "15466982416256137216.0 / 2^53"